# HTML canvas not scrolling window on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, mobile

I have a problem, trying to scroll window while touching mobile canvas. This only happens for Android Chrome, and works on ios Chrome and default mobile web browsers.

I don't know where the problem is because of getting the canvas applied to a surface by a 3rd party client, and i'm not able to modify that code.

Any suggestion?
Defining an own scroll function would be one.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for this, and no longer need a answer.
The canvas had the style attribute `touch-action: none`.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and that fixed it for me !